# How to escape in foreach in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, escaping, permalinks

I have a Wordpress site and I am trying to fetch posts from a specific category. That works, but now I want to link to the specific posts with a permalink. I could not getting it to work with escaping in a foreach. Can someone tell me/show me what I am doing wrong here?

```
<?php 
   global $post; // required
   $args = array('category' => 9); // include category 9
   $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
   foreach($custom_posts as $post) : 
      setup_postdata($post);
      echo "<a href='.the_permalink().'> the_title() </a> ";
      the_excerpt();

//and so on.. 

   endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is. Please demonstrate what it does and what you wanted it to do.

Comment: See @joshtronic's answer. He understood it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually closing your quotes properly and aren't using the correct functions. Line 5 should read more like:

```
the_title("<a href='".get_permalink()."'>",'</a>',true);
```

BOOM.

Comment: Boom, worked like a charm. Thanks man! But can you explain to me how you can put the title between the a tags with a comma like you did? I don't understand that...

Comment: Yeah, that's just how the `the_title()` works, unsure why they don't offer up a `get_title()` function to complement the `get_permalink()`. Basically the function takes 3 arguments: `$before`, `$after` and `$echo`. Before and after just need to be the tags that are going to wrap the title and echo tells it if it outta return the string or immediately echo. Just a WP thing really: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title